# Prevent user to close tab or browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

Is that possible to start a loop on window.onbeforeunload to open same current page again and again on tab exit? check following code, its working but browser blocking it as popup opening.

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
       window.open(document.URL,"_blank");
       return 'Dialog text here.';
    };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q9kd4b0x/

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Can you explain me reason?

Comment: I'm curious as to the purpose? Seems like a unethical way to run a web app

Comment: Well its for learning purpose. You we concentrate on its solution or Possible reason why that not possible it will be good. And its open forum for discussion?

Comment: To allow that would constitute a browser security issue. People really don't like it when websites do things like that, so browsers do not allow it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_security

Comment: @pointy you are answering wrong question, i;m not asking for reason behind not allowing this thing. I'm asking "Why Its not possible?". I think its possible and i put some example code.

Comment: @SairaKanwal _"i;m not asking for reason behind not allowing this thing. I'm asking "Why Its not possible?"."_ Appears to be same Question ?

Comment: It is not possible because people want it not to be possible. Web browsers deliberately will not allow code in a "beforeunload" handler to open a new window. They do that because people who maintain web browsers all agreed that would be a good idea. You're free to implement your own web browser that makes it possible.

Comment: @SairaKanwal What are you trying to achieve by the process ? Yes, it appears to be possible; `js` at Question at https://jsfiddle.net/q9kd4b0x/ returns expected results, here, though does not move focus to the newly opened `tab`.

Comment: @guest271314 ?? That fiddle does not work. It's possible to close the its browser tab without anything happening at all.

Comment: @SairaKanwal if it's possible, why does the jsfiddle not work?

Comment: @Pointy At chromium 50 , at https://jsfiddle.net/q9kd4b0x/, if click `x` to close current `tab`, a new `tab` is opened adjacent to the current `tab`. OP asked if it is possible, not for all caveats; such as new `tab` not gaining `focus` ; settings or `flags` that user may or may not have implemented at specific browser.

Comment: @Pointy OP is, perhaps, expected newly opened `tab` to gain `focus`; or for all users that visit page to have popup blockers disabled

Comment: @guest271314 Doesn't work in Firefox 44 or Chrome 49. You might want to log a Chromium bug :) The issue is that a "beforeunload" event loop is not (or at least should not) be one that allows windows to be opened.

Comment: @Pointy probably not a bug; but can look into it. Have a number of flags set for chromium instance that may affect what is possible, or not possible. Have had a difficult time locating `webkit` documentations Why would a new `window` or `tab` not be able to opened, unless user has some form of popup blocker implemented at `settings` ?. What would the bug be ? Again, OP is, perhaps, expected the new `window` not to open in a new `tab`, but somehow cover the entire existing `tab`; though this may be an inaccurate interpretation of requirement.

Comment: @guest271314 Browsers (since several years ago) all have *intrinsic* popup blockers. The `window.open()` function only works in certain types of event loops, generally things like "click" that involve explicit user interaction with part of the page.

Comment: @guest271314 that can be disabled selectively by the browser user, if the user can figure out how. The page code can't disable it however (otherwise it'd be a broken popup blocker).

Comment: Seems like a HACKER post. It should not have a way to do this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that possible to start a loop on window.onbeforeunload to open same
>   current page again and again on tab exit?

Yes.

> Why Its not possible?
>
> but browser blocking it as popup opening

Your popup blocker is turned on at the browser you are testing the `javascript` at to prevent this browser behaviour by default; or by the setting that you have implemented.

Solution: Turn off the popup blocker at the browser that  you are viewing https://jsfiddle.net/q9kd4b0x/ at .

A new  `window` at a new `tab` should open at each `onbeforeunload` event

Comment: Note, at chromium `settings` of browser  -> `Content settings` -> `Pop-ups` select `Allow all sites to show popups`; or similar implementation at other browser